# Can't inject constant to other modules angularjs ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, global-variables, constants, angular-module

I want to use constant variables which can be called from anywhere in the project.

I made 'constants.js'.

```
angular.module('myApp.constants', [])

.constant('const', (function(){

  return {
    username = 'abc'
  }
})()
);
```

'app.js'

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.constants'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

  });
})
```

'controllers.js'

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $http, $state, const) {
  $scope.user_name = const.username;
});
```

When I called 'const' from controller, I got this error.

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js: Line 8 : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js
```

I'm not familiar with angularjs and its module.
I hope someone can send me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your constant like this

```
angular.module('myApp.constants', []).constant('const', {username: 'abc'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp.constants', [])

.constant('constantMessage', (function(){
    return {
        username : 'abc'
    }
})());
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.constants'])
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,constantMessage) {
  $scope.user_name = constantMessage.username;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
  {{user_name}}
  </div>
```

Please update your `constant.js` file to :

```
.constant('constantMessage', (function(){
    return {
        username : 'abc'
    }
})());
```

Then check it..

Comment: I think it's the same thing I wrote in my constant.js

Comment: please change the name "const" to any other name because angular take  "const" as default keyword  and use ":" instead of "="

Comment: I changed the name as 'CommonConstants' and I got this error.'ReferenceError: CommonConstants is not defined'

Comment: in above code make "constant.js" file and in include in  index.html